# Усилительное значение частицы "да"

Tags: лексика

Да - многозначное слово (притом что его основное значение  - это утверждение, согласие). Например, в словаре указано усилительное значение:

8. Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности. Да что с вами говорить!  Да кто вы такой? Да тебе-то что за дело? Куда идти? - Да прямо!  Где? - Да вон там.* Скажи, которая Татьяна? - Да та, которая грустна (Пушкин).

И самые удивительные сочетания: *да нет;* *да нет, наверное*.

Интересно, как связано это  усилительное значение с утвердительным? Что изменится, если убрать "да" (сказать: вон там)?